# how to condition a change in groupby based on just one row of the group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to change on column in a groupby based on the condition in a single line in the groupby

I have a data that looks like this:

```
ID  year    month   type

1   2008    1       A

1   2008    2       NAN

1   2009    1       B

2   2003    3       B

2  2003     4       B

2  2003     8       A

3  2009     9       B
```

I want to change the data in the following way:
For each ID, if there is a row for Jan or Feb 2008 with a non-NAN value for Type, for all rows for the dates between Jan 2008 to Dec 2009 replace the type with the type of the row for Fab 2008 if it exists or Jan 2008 if it doesn't

I've tried using .groupby(id).isin({'year':[2008],'month':[1,2]}).any() but it just generates a new boolian variable rather than change the existing variable

Comment: What is it you are trying to group? Also, why don't you apply your changes and only then group the data?

Answer (score 0):

Why not enforce strict types for all rows? Then your problem is simplified to:

```
month_years = df.loc[:, ['year', 'month']]
updated_types = get_default_types(month_years)
updated_df = df.assign(type=updated_types)
```

Comment: Or you could use the apply() method of DataFrame: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Comment: My main issue is how do to condition the function by the existence of a row that follows ((df.groupby('id').loc['year'== 2008, 'month'==1]) | (df.groupby('id').loc['year'== 2008, 'month'==2)) & (df.groupby('id).'type'.notna())